# Why only two atoms share an electron and not three?

Tags: electrons, orbitals

In a [covalent bond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond) between two [atoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atoms), an [electron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron) from one of the either atom is shared by overlapping of their [orbitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital).

So,
**Why can't three atoms share an electron and overlap their orbitals?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The normal case for a covalent bond is indeed a **2-centre 2-electron** bond.

There are however cases, where 3 centres (= atoms) either share 2 or 4 electrons.

- In organic chemistry, the most famous case for an *electron-deficient* **3-centre 2-electron** bond is the [2-norbornyl cation](http://www.rsc.org/chemistryworld/2013/07/norbornyl-cation-nonclassical-structure-olah-herb-brown).
- In inorganic chemistry, boranes with their [banana bonds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/228/what-makes-banana-bonds-possible-in-diborane) are the role models.

*Hypervalent* molecules with **3-centre 4-electron** bonds, like [$\ce{SF6}$](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/why-do-compounds-like-sf6-and-sf4-exist-but-sh6-and-sh4-dont/4762#4762) or the bifluoride anion [$\ce{HF2-}$](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8549/existence-and-stability-of-bifluoride-ion) have been discussed here too.

Comment: @AwalGarg Maybe I misunderstood your question then. In a "normal" covalent bond, the **two** atoms (centres) share **two** electrons, one valence electron from each partner. They are not sharing **one**, but **two** electrons. It appeared to me that you were asking for the "less normal" cases.

Comment: @AwalGarg In organic chemistry, I'm not aware of anything more electron-deficient than the non-classical cations (3-centre 2-electrons) and I doubt that something like 5-centre 2-electrons exists even as an extremely short-lived intermediate. On the other hand, what about metallic bonds in a crystal lattice: Is this the case for an $\infty$-centre $\infty$-electrons system?

Comment: Ok, then let's take a step back and look at the organic electron deficient cases. In the case of the norbornyl cation, we could imagine that to be like a normal $\ce{C-C}$ bond plus a cationic centre near by that wants to mix in. For a larger number of centres, sharing the same number (2) of electrons, I see two problems (i) lack of binding force: what will hold them together and (ii) geometrical restrictions: how will all these atoms manage sufficient orbital overlap. So, unless proven otherwise, I'd say 3-centres 2-electrons is the end of the road here.

Comment: But I'm sure some guys here, well-versed in theoretical chemistry, might want to give some (less pictorial) answers too :)